# BigQuery SUM function surprising behavior

Tags: sql, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

BigQuery SUM function is returning (-0.0) dealing with float datatype.
Really surprised to see negative Zero. It only happens when applied with WINDOW function on float datatype like below.

```
select sum(x) over (partition by test) from (SELECT x,test FROM UNNEST([-5.5,5.5]) AS x, UNNEST(['ab','ab']) as test);      **--returns -0.0**
```

But it's computation is fine with Integer type of data.

```
select sum(x) over (partition by test) from (SELECT x,test FROM UNNEST([-5,5]) AS x, UNNEST(['ab','ab']) as test);     **--returns 0.0**
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I would probably submit this to the BQ issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659

Comment: I have just done it. Let's wait.

Comment: Hi can you post the link to the issue tracker you opened please

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149039426